# Should all my buttons be the same size if they are on different screens?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, users, experience

So I have a concept where you select a category, and underneath that category select another sub category, which will then show the history of that category. The screenshot just shows the subcategory and the history, but there is a main category section above this. Given that the subcategories can vary in #, I am struggling whether they should stay the same size, or different sizes depending on the number of subcategories. This app would be mainly target towards seniors, so larger the better. Should I keep them all the same size, or make them different sizes like the wireframe below.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Size communicates importance, and it could be confusing as to why some categories are "larger" than others. Opt to stay consistent with the sizing, even if they don't all fit on one line. (Circles are notoriously tricky when it comes to scaling and variable width information fitting inside of them, so you might want to try other container options.)